# AppId validation in nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, proxy, lua

I am attempting to write a reverse proxy to direct client s3 document requests through nginx. It appears that there is a reasonable start using nginx [here](https://gist.github.com/sansmischevia/5617402). However, we would like to add the ability to have a client pass an "appid" or token that we generate for each client that gets validated prior to redirecting to the s3 document. I'm not entirely sure of hor to do this. Is it possible with native nginx? Will it require custom logic in lua?

To be clear, here are the specific requirements:

1. Static hosted site with unchanging links to documents in s3 (a workaround to the s3 expiring links limit of 7 days)
2. Ability to pass an appid/token that can be invalidated and regenerated given any suspicious/malicious activity.

Comment: As interesting as this question is, I'm unsure whether it's on topic here, since a question like this is typically expected to include "here's the code I have written so far"... but, having designed several different solutions to this problem, I am left lacking a full understanding your objectives: how many "tokens" are there (per user? per file?) and how does a user come into possession of the token?  Info about what other components are in your stack would be useful as well, since there may be ways to leverage them.

Answer (score 0):

If your token is already accessible from nginx then you could just add it as a header using a custom header with proxy_set_header, examples [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/598202/make-nginx-to-pass-hostname-of-the-upstream-when-reverseproxying).